# Update Multi Lookup Field in Document Library Using REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, rest

I'm using below code to update multiple lookup fields of document library

**Code:**

```
var itemProperties = { '__metadata': { "type": "SP.Data.WP_x005f_DocumentsListItem" }, 'Technology_StackId': { "results": [1,2] }} // multi-valued field }

$.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items(" + itemId + ")",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(itemProperties),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
            "If-Match": '*'
        },
        success: function (data) {
            success();
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
});
```

It is throwing below error:

> A type named 'SP.Data.WP_x005f_DocumentsListItem' could not be
>   resolved by the model. When a model is available, each type name must
>   resolve to a valid type

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: can you check `SP.Data.WP_x005f_DocumentsListItem` is correct? You can find by a GET request to `/_api/Web/Lists/getbytitle('List Name')/ListItemEntityTypeFullName`

Comment: i have checked that it is correct

Comment: This error is only related to `ListItemEntityTypeFullName` as far as I know

https://nishantrana.me/2013/10/03/a-type-named-sp-data-listitem-could-not-be-resolved-by-the-model-when-a-model-is-available-each-type-name-must-resolve-to-a-valid-type-error-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: ya also know that but not able to update the field

Comment: Is it happen for this column only? Can you update other column except this